# How to open buttons of datatable in a new tab?

Tags: lightning-datatable, lightning-button

I am using a datatable to show record details. It has a view button that will take the user to the respective record. I want to open record in a new tab. Right-clicking a button does not show the `open in new tab` option. Action, phone, URL, email, etc show that option. How can we make a button open in a new tab by clicking it; or at least right-clicking it?

I declared button as follows (added `target:'_blank'`):

```js
const columns = [
    {
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button',
        initialWidth: 50,
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'View',
            title: 'View',
            variant: 'base',
            alternativeText: 'View',
            target:'_blank'
        }
    },
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name', type:'text' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email' , sortable:'true' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone', sortable:'true'  },
    { label: 'MDM ID', fieldName: 'mdm', type: 'text' , editable:'true' },
];
```

HTML

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="LWC Wrapper Component" icon-name="standard:contact">
        <div style="height: 400px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={wrappers.data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowaction={navigateToRecordViewPage}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>    
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

> Button does not show `open in a new tab` option

[image: Button does not show option to open in a new tab]

> Action shows option to open in new tab

[image: Action shows option to open in new tab]

**Updates:**

I added `window.open()` to navigation logic of button. It opens a new undefined tab and opens record in same tab.

> This page is opened in new tab (The record opens in previous tab)
>
> > [image: This page is opened in new tab (The record opens in previous tab)]

Javascript

```js
import { LightningElement,api,track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getWrapperLis from '@salesforce/apex/WrapperClass.getWrapperList';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation'; ///Navigation



const columns = [
    {
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button',
        initialWidth: 50,
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'View',
            title: 'View',
            variant: 'base',
            alternativeText: 'View',
            target:'_blank'
        }
    },
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name', type:'text' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email' , sortable:'true' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone', sortable:'true'  },
    { label: 'MDM ID', fieldName: 'mdm', type: 'text' , editable:'true' },
];

export default class WrapperClassTestNavigation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track columns = columns;
    
    // @api UserContext;
    @wire(getWrapperLis,{lead:'$recordId'}) wrappers;

    navigateToRecordViewPage(event) {
        this.record = event.detail.row;
        
        if(document.referrer.indexOf(".lightning.force.com") > 0){
            window.open(
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.record.id,
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            }),"_blank");
        }else{
            window.open(window.location.assign('/'+this.record.id),"_blank");
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**added**

You should use [GenerateUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) for your use case:

```
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.record.id,
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    }).then(url => {
        console.log('url => ', url); // Verify that you are getting url in log.
        window.open(url, "_blank");
    });
```

---

It does not show the option ***Open in new tab*** because the click event has a reference which in-turn has the actual logic for navigating. If you had ***href*** attribute in anchor tag, then you will get the option. However, you can still use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) in the method as below:

Column:

```
{
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button',
        initialWidth: 50,
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'View',
            name: 'view_details',
            recordId: { fieldName: 'Id' },
            title: 'View',
            variant: 'base',
            alternativeText: 'View',
            target: '_blank'
        }
    },
```

You need `name` and `recordId` properties as shown above. Now in the [row action handler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example):

```
handleRowAction(event) {
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row;
    switch (actionName) {
        case 'view_details':
            window.open(row.recordId, "_blank");
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question at the end. I added window.open() to navigation logic of button. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this Javascript function for navigation:

```js
navigateToRecordViewPage(event) {
        this.record = event.detail.row;
        if(this.UserContext != undefined) {
            if(this.UserContext != 'Theme4t' || this.UserContext != 'Theme4d') {
                window.location.assign(window.open('/'+this.record.id,"_blank"));
            } 
        }
        else{
            this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.record.id,
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            }).then(url => {
                window.open(url,"_blank");
            });
        }
    }
```